# What are the prerequisite knowledge needed to start solving crackmes?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, debugging, crackme, game-hacking

I started by reading a book on C language and then moved on to "Programming From Ground Up," which teaches basic programming in x86.

School just ended, I'm working on cracking a game called PwnAdventure Sourcery, which has been tough. I had to look up solutions and found that some involved buffer overflow and bruteforcing algorithms. It took me around 30 minutes to finally look up for a solution, and I feel like I'm so stupid :(

If possible, can you give a rough roadmap for reverse engineering along with some great resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are innumerable paths... but for some getting started material:

- https://p.ost2.fyi/ :: Open Security Training 2, Xeno has rebooted the project and has tons of great, free, in-depth courses.
- https://beginners.re/ :: Denis Yurichevs on-line book (or PDF)
- https://github.com/crackmes/crackmes :: a crackmes.de mirror, start at level 1, some are very easy but the variety of compilers makes it a good way to build up your tool set
- http://www.binary-auditing.com/ :: The Binary Auditor course teaches binary analysis and some C at the same time

There is literally tons of material available, some holds it's own over the years and some doesn't... but this list is some that I remember being very accessible, enjoy the journey!